# Como adicionar o grupo BUILTIN\\Administrators no SQL Server para Sistemas Operacionais que não estão em Inglês?

Tags: c#, sql-server, segurança

Durante a instalação da minha aplicação em um servidor, a seguinte linha é executada:

```
using (var com = con.CreateCommand())
{
    com.CommandText = "CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS";
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Esse código funciona bem quando executado em sistemas operacionais em Inglês, mas quando eu tentei executar em um sistema operacional em Português não funcionou.

Qual seria, então, o comando correto, de forma que esse código possa ser executado em qualquer sistema operacional, independente do idioma?

Comment: Chegou a testar trocando Administrators por Administradores? Só para ver se funciona?

Comment: Vou testar isso agora, e acredito que deve funcionar. Mas eu não tenho como saber qual o idioma do sistema operacional que será instalado. Então eu ainda preciso de um comando para executar em qualquer SO, ou pelo menos alguma forma de pegar a string correta do sistema.

Comment: Em se tratando de Windows, vai ser dificil seguir um padrão. Se o seu caso se trata apenas de instalações inglês/português, você poderia criar um if testando o idioma e aí sim executar seu comando.

Comment: Meu caso se trata de qualquer instalação, em qualquer idioma, pois essa aplicação poderá ser usada em qualquer país do mundo. Estou pesquisando como pegar o nome "BUILTIN\\Administrators" em qualquer idioma.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Existe uma forma de recuperar nomes de grupos conhecidos, como o grupo de Administradores, usando SID. Vou postar uma resposta explicando. Obrigado pela ajuda Diego!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema da seguinte forma:

Para grupos conhecidos, como Administradores (Administrators) e Convidados (Guests), é possível recuperar o nome baseado no SID (Secutiry Identifier). Uma lista de SIDs conhecidos está disponível [aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330):

Para esse caso específico, o grupo de Administradores possui o SID = "S-1-5-32-544". Assim, segue abaixo a solução final:

```
string sidBuiltinAdmins = "S-1-5-32-544";
string builtinAdmins = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(sidBuiltinAdmins).Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
using (var com = con.CreateCommand())
{
    com.CommandText = string.Format("CREATE LOGIN [{0}] FROM WINDOWS", builtinAdmins);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```